# httpclient SchemeRegistryFactory.createSystemDefault no such method Error

Tags: maven, solr, apache-httpclient-4.x

i am using solr 4.8.1,

i am unable to insert document into solr,
this is the stack trace

```
14/06/13 20:10:57 INFO impl.HttpClientUtil: Creating new http client, config:maxConnections=128&maxConnectionsPerHost=32&followRedirects=false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createSystemDefault()Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeRegistry;
at org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(SystemDefaultHttpClient.java:118)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:445)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.setMaxConnections(HttpClientUtil.java:179)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientConfigurer.configure(HttpClientConfigurer.java:33)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.configureClient(HttpClientUtil.java:115)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createClient(HttpClientUtil.java:105)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.<init>(HttpSolrServer.java:154)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.<init>(HttpSolrServer.java:127)
at com.serendio.icvs.IcvsSolr.<init>(IcvsSolr.java:29)
at com.serendio.icvs.hbase.tools.TestSolr.main(TestSolr.java:36)
```

pom has httpclient 4.2.3 version
can't figure out what's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured it out,
there's a mismatch in org apache httpclient with commons-httpclient dependency 
present in hadoop mahout and hbase artifacts of pom,
i tried mvn dependecy:tree 
then i figured this dependency issue,

after excluding commons-httpclient from hadoop hbase and mahout solr program is running.

Comment: This actually helped me in finding out the error with my code. 
I had a similar dependency issue, which was only happening during runtime.